# Is there any way to enforce WAF rules to already existing objects in cloudfront/S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

im trying to serve private content via cloudfront. For this, I have added WAF rule and applied it to cloudfront which seems working fine for new upload files. But the same is not working for the old file which already exists in cloudfront and file is easily accessible via cloudfront itself. (Cloudfront is serving the content from S3 bucket and secured by cross-origin)

Comment: WAF rules apply immediately to the entire distribution. This suggests that you are seeing objects from your browser cache, or that your WAF rules do not do what you are trying to do.  An example of a request that should be denied, and why it should be denied, will be helpful.

Comment: Note also that "secured by cross-origin" is not a valid concept.  CORS is not a security mechanism for protecting your content from unauthorized access.  It is only designed to give well-behaved browsers permission to access the content.  A user-agent that wants to bypass any CORS-based restriction is completely free to do so.